# Adding ability to allow user to select a color theme for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, themes

I redesigning our corporate Intranet.  I'm using a simple theme based on 5 related colors to create a uniform style across all pages.  One thing I'd like to do is allow each user to select their own "theme".  It's easy enough to create multiple color pallets that will work with my design.  What I'm toying with is the best way to implement this.

I had two thoughts, but I'm open to all suggestions.  The first would be to create a base style sheet that is theme independent and uniformly apply that.  Then create separate theme style sheets.  Then applying that either through server side scripting or JavaScript/jQuery.  My other thought is to use one style sheet then use jQuery to apply the them to each element.  So for example:

```
<div class="theme_color_1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function colorize(theme){
         if(theme === 0){
             $('.theme_color_1').addClass('blue_theme_1');
         }
         else if(theme === 1){
             $('.theme_color_1').addClass('red_theme_1');
         }
         else{
             $('.theme_color_1').addClass('default_theme_1');
         }
    }
</script>
```

And so one for each theme item.  I'm just wondering if anyone has experience implementing this type of function and what you believe the "best" method is.  Our site is fairly "light" so I'm not terribly concerned with processing/speed when it comes to DOM manipulation or page loading.

Thanks!

**I just used a very simple code example as I have not started to implement this yet.  If my code is not explanatory enough please let me know and I'll provide additional details.

**Also please note that I am using Classic ASP (it's what I'm stuck with for the time being), MS SQL, HTML 5, CSS 3 (using PIE to provide feature support), JavaScript, jQuery, and jQuery UI.

Comment: Add a class to the body, style based off that class. Store the setting in the database, add it to the body tag when page renders. TADA, you are done.

Comment: Interesting, not sure why I didn't think of that.  That would certainly be less overhead and I could use a single style sheet and a single jQuery/JavaScript function.  I' still in the planning stages but once I get to that point I'll give it a try and update this question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the theme selected by the user in the database and depending on the user logged in apply the stylesheet.

e.g.

```
<% if rs("style") = 1 then %>
<link href="theme1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% elseif rs("style") = 2 then %>
<link href="theme2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...etc.
```

Having a base theme is absolutely a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the possible solutions I am going to use.  I haven't gotten to the development stage where I can apply this.  Right now I'm just developing the core css such that I can have themes.  Once I get far enough down field then I'll try a few of the suggestions here.